# JS call method, why not just use brackets?

Tags: javascript

So, I've got some code that looks like this (genericised from a closed-source project).

```
UserWizard = {
  init: function(name) {
    this.firstInit.call(name);
    this.secondInit.call(name);
  },

  firstInit: function(name) {
    // ...
  },
  secondInit: function(name) {
     // ...
  }

}
```

It's the first time I've ever seen the call method used in JS and it appears to be exactly the same as just calling the function with brackets, e.g.

```
this.firstInit(name);
```

So what is `call` doing here? Does it act any differently?

Comment: The first argument to `call` is the value of `this` not the first argument of the function.

Comment: The code as posted would appear to be not entirely right, unless it's _expecting_ the `name` argument in `firstInit` and `secondInit` to be `undefined`.

Comment: I'm abbreviating, adding some placeholders

Comment: Reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is always useful.

Comment: `.call` like `.apply` allows you to specify a `this` context. You can for instance do: `var remain = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);` This would not be possible with a 'normal' function call.

Comment: `()` are *parentheses*, "brackets" are these things: `[]`.

Comment: If you abbreviate in such a way that it changes the code, it is impossible for us to answer the question.

Comment: It's also worthwhile reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this which describes how "this" (sometimes surprisingly) changes depending on the context.

Comment: I'm never touching JavaScript again. The community is pedantic, unhelpful and rude.

Comment: @AJFaraday What's JavaScript got to do with the SO community? Yea some peoples comments were a bit sarcastic but still plenty or helpful links and even an answer that explains it completely for a question that is about the core of JavaScript, context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling

```
UserWizard.init('some name');
```

The `this` object of the `firstInit` and the `secondInit` functions will be the string 'some name' and the parameter `name` value will be `undefined`

```
UserWizard.firstInit('some name')
```

Is the same as:

```
UserWizard.firstInit.call(UserWizard, 'some name');
```

Hope I was clear

Comment: Thanks, this is the detail I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

`call()` is not doing what you think it's doing here. It's actually changing the context of `this` within both `firstInit` and `secondInit`.

[Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is the link to the mozilla docs, quoting from there there:

> A different this object can be assigned when calling an existing function. this refers to the current object, the calling object. With call, you can write a method once and then inherit it in another object, without having to rewrite the method for the new object. - by Mozilla Contributors

There's another function [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which I'd encourage you to look at. I find generally I use this more often, but it's a similar sort of idea, used to assign `this` to the function when it may get called later on. This is good for preventing issues like:

```
var person = {
    name: 'First Last',
    getName: function (){
        return this.name;
    }
};

var getName = person.getName;
getName(); // returns undefined as `this` is the global window object
```